# Stochastic Gradient Descent for Logistic Regression always returns a cost of Inf and weight vector never gets any closer

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, regression, logistic-regression

I am trying to implement a logistic regression solver in MATLAB and i am finding the weights by stochastic gradient descent. I am running into a problem where my data seems to produce an infinite cost, and no matter what happens it never goes down...
Both these seem perfectly fine, i cant imagine why my cost function would ALWAYS return infinite.

[Here is my training data](http://pastebin.com/Upy0J1bU) where the first column is the class (Either 1 or 0) and the next seven columns are the features i am trying to regress on.

Comment: I think this has to do with log(0) being -Inf..

Comment: Personally, I like more to express the weight update as: `weightVector = weightVector - learningRate * gradient`. I see more clearly that we move in the opposite direction of the gradient towards a minima of the cost function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your gradient has the wrong sign:

> gradient = learningRate .* (trueClass(m) - predictedClass) .* transpose([1.0 features(m,:)])

It should be:

> gradient = learningRate .* (predictedClass - trueClass(m)) .* transpose([1.0 features(m,:)])

See Andrew Ng's [note](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.pdf) for details.
The gradient with respect to the j-th parameter is obtained as below: (where `h(x)` is the logistic function; `y` is the true label; `x` is the feature vector.)
[image]

Otherwise, when you take the negative of gradient you are doing gradient ascend. I believe that 's why you eventually get infinite cost since it's dead loop and you never get out of it.

The update rule should still be:

> weightVector = weightVector - gradient

Comment: Thank you for the mathematical explanation, the link seems to be broken to me, could you fix it?

Comment: Even after fixing this in my implementation it still results in infinite cost. I have tried both adding and subtracting of the gradient from my weights and the cost is always infinite.

Comment: Can you add code to check your gradient? http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Gradient_checking_and_advanced_optimization